# Phpstorm wrong Highlighting

Tags: phpstorm, highlighting

There are strange errors in twig files. First of all there is a dark green background, the other problem is "statement expected".

I tried to "Invalidate cache" but it does not help.

the only thing that helps is just to put "Power Save Mode" that totally disable code analyse.

screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTL1q.jpg

Answer (score 5):

There are injected language fragments. Point mouse there, press Alt+Enter and select Un-inject language/reference.

Comment: thanks for answer, I have changed "Language injection settings", it as set as javascript, so I changed to html. So red lines disappeared but dark green background still.